¿Cómo cambiar la estructura de una tabla de sql con multiples condiciones?
No tengo conocimiento de sql y necesito transformar una consulta una ventana de una base de datos en la que tengo el id de muestra en la primera columna, en la segunda el id del resultado (id_aislado, concentración) y en la tercera el valor del resultado ("S.epidermidis", "10E5"). A cada id_aislado le corresponde una concentración, para una muestra; una única muestra puede tener varios resultados y no tienen porque coincidir los id. Como puedo cambiar la estructura de mi tabla de forma que cada id de muestra sea una única fila y tenga una columna para cada id_aislado y en la intersección correspondiente aparezca cada concentración?.
Este es un ejemplo de la vista:



sample_id
Result.name
Format.entry




1596
id.isolate
S. haemolyticus


1596
Concentration
2.00E1


1596
id.isolate
S. epidermidis


1596
Concentration
1.00E1


1596
id.isolate
Lb. crispatus


1596
Concentration
3.80E5


1447
id.isolate
Lb. jensenii


1447
Concentration
1.03E6


1458
id.isolate
S. haemolyticus


1458
Concentration
3.90E2


1458
id.isolate
S. epidermidis


1458
Concentration
4.00E1


1458
id.isolate
Ent. faecalis


1458
Concentration
3.80E5


1458
id.isolate
Lb. crispatus


1458
Concentration
1.03E6


1458
id.isolate
E. coli


1458
Concentration
7.00E0



y necesito transformarlo así:



Sample_id
S. epidermidis
S. haemolyticus
Lb. crispatus
Lb. jensenii
Ent. faecalis
E. coli




1596
1.60E1
2.00E1
3.80E5





1447



1.03E6




1458
4.00E1
3.90E2
5.80E1

1.40E2
7.00E0



Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida.
Gracias

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. ¡También, aprovecha y haz él [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!, esto es una tabla pivotante, y su construcción depende totalmente del motor que estés usando...

Antes de resolver esto, necesitas una forma de asegurar el orden y la relación entre las filas. No hay nada que garantice que 2.00E1 pertenece a S. haemolyticus puesto que dentro de una tabla/vista no hay un orden definido. Sin nada que defina el orden, esta consulta está destinada a dar información incorrecta en algun momento.

Para dar una buena respuesta sería bueno saber:

si el numero de isolates es controlado o si pueden haber resultados para isolates nuevos que no estén en la muestra de datos existente
qué motor de base de datos estás usando
si la base de datos ya está en producción y con datos

Quizás una buena opción a considerar sería en vez de pasar cada isolate a columnas, pensar en la posibilidad de poner los resultados como una columna JSON. Hoy en día muchas BD tienen buen soporte para JSON pero va a depender de que engine uses
